# Check Phone Call State Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

In my application I am calling some phone numbers progrmatically. is there any way i can check if the call beep is going and connection is established to ensure the validity of a phone number and end call before pick up.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Firstly you have to add the following Permissions in manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>`

2) Then you have to define a broadcast receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".AnswerCallBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Then add the following code in your broadcast receiver

```
public class AnswerCallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        if(arg1.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){

            String state = arg1.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside Extra state off hook");
                String number = arg1.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                Log.e(TAG, "outgoing number : " + number);              
            }       

            else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){   
                Log.e(TAG, "Inside EXTRA_STATE_RINGING");
                String number = arg1.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Log.e(TAG, "incoming number : " + number);
            }
            else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                Log.d(TAG, "Inside EXTRA_STATE_IDLE");
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guess your code because you didn't give me any clue :(

In order to get the phone call states you should add a listener to the [Telephony Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE).

create a listener class:

```
// Or just make new PhoneStateListener() and override onCallStateChanged
public class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
            //A new call arrived and is ringing or waiting. In the latter case, another call is already active
        }

        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
            //At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting
        }

        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            //No activity
        }
    }
}
```

Add the listener:

```
PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

After you are listening to the phone call status, you should start the phone call itself in a way like that:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
CallInfo callInfo = new CallInfo(PHONE_NUMBER);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + callInfo.getDialTo()));
//** Check for permision **//
startActivity(callIntent);
```

In order to make this happen right, you must get the permission to perform a call and listen to phone call states, so add the following permissions to your manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```